# How to concatenate aggregated rows unless one column equals a certain value in SQL?

Tags: sql, h2

I am having trouble coming up with a working SQL query in H2 to achieve my goal. I would like to aggregate and concatenate rows based on the values of both the `Day/s` and `Join` columns. However, I would like for it to **not** concatenate the values if the `Join` column is an empty string.

```
Course | Day/s | Join 
---------------------
class1 | M W F | 111
class2 | M W F | 111
class3 | T R   |
class4 | T R   |
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
Course        | Day/s | Join 
-----------------------------
class1 class2 | M W F | 111
class3        |  T R  |
class4        |  T R  |
```

The closest I've gotten is

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Course" ORDER BY "Id" SEPARATOR ' ') AS "Course",
       "Day/s",
       "Join"
From SAMPLE
GROUP BY "Day/s", "Join" HAVING "Join" <> ''
```

But this omits rows altogether when `Join` equals an empty string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *But this omits rows altogether when Join equals an empty string.*: just remove `HAVING "Join" <> ''`

Comment: @GMB That results in `class3` and `class4` being concatenated, which is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Course" ORDER BY "Id" SEPARATOR ' ') AS "Course",
    "Day/s",
    "Join"
    FROM SAMPLE
    WHERE "Join" <> ''
    GROUP BY "Day/s", "Join"
UNION ALL
    SELECT "Course", "Day/s", "Join"
    FROM SAMPLE
    WHERE "Join" = ''
```

Note that `NULL` is neither equal nor unequal to the empty string `''`, if you have `NULL` values in the `"Join"` column you need to add an explicit null check to the `WHERE` clause.

If you want to remove possible duplicate rows with empty `"Join"` column, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.